# MagicZoom JS Issue

Tags: javascript, magiczoom

I am using Magic zoom plus on my magento website,
I found magic zoom will generate lots of JS in the html body.
Please see following screenshot

http://screencast.com/t/emzgCN1Sazr

http://screencast.com/t/uoABDzfL

I know some of them are based on the settings from the magic zoom in admin panel.Those scripts control the layout of the magic zoom.

My question is:

Once the setting finished, there is no needs to edit them.

How can I remove these JS from the html body?

We want put those JS under the JS file and then request the JS.

Answer (score 0):

- Create 2 separate JavaScript files with your chosen Magic Zoom Plus and Magic Scroll settings.
- Upload the two .js files to your server.
- Reference the two files in the following files:
  app/code/local/MagicToolbox/MagicZoomPlus/core/magiczoomplus.module.core.class.php 
  app/code/local/MagicToolbox/MagicZoomPlus/core/magicscroll.module.core.class.php

Regarding your screenshots, there is a function getHeadersTemplate which generates the code from your first screenshot. You're not recommended to change any code in your last screenshot.

As a general rule, you're advised to always use the latest version of the Magento extension, which is updated regularly and available to [download here](http://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoomplus/modules/magento/).